# router.query returning an empty object in next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next-router

my folder structure:

[image]

also my code:

```js
const router = useRouter();
const { id } = router.query;
```

so the problem is the id is returning `{}` and is not returning the id in the URL. it works fine when I put it in jsx but not when I put it in js

Comment: u sure u using `import { useRouter } from "next/router";`, i think get stuck in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should name folder is "duc" or "product" or ...  and in folder name js should [id].js for dynamic route , not index.js

[Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)